# With-binding not working for ko.computed()

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I´m struggling with a ko.computed-function ans the with binding.
When a button "New" is pressed, I want to show an empty input-text field.
when selecting from the dropdownlist, I want the text-field to show the selected optionsText from the dropdownlist.

This is from the viewModel.js:

---

```
// selected item from ticket drop down
self.selectedItem = ko.observable(null);

// status of button "New"
self.newIsPushed = ko.observable(false);

self.showName = ko.computed(function () {
        // logic for calculating when to show Name. 
        return (self.newIsPushed() && (self.selectedItem() ? (null) : true));
    }, self);
```

---

From my ascx-file:

---

```
<select data-bind="options: ticketCollection, 
                   optionsCaption: 'Choose...', 
                   optionsText: 'ticketname', 
                   value: selectedItem"></select> 

<button type="button" name="btnNew"
   data-bind="click: newTicket, disable: newIsPushed">New</button> 

<p data-bind="with: showName"> 
   <label>Name: <input type="text" 
   data-bind="value: ticketname" /></label><br />
</p>
```

Why isn´t the input-field updated when I either push the "New"-button or selects another item from my ddl ???

Cheers!

Asle :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<p data-bind="with: showName">` with `<p data-bind="with: selectedItem">`

Comment: Thanks, Anders!
Appreciate it!